# How to register tapgesture on MKAnnotationView image?

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, mkmapview, mkannotation

Is there a way to register tapgesture within the image of `MKAnnotationView` ?

Basically my anotation view looks like this, it has no title, no subtitle, only custom image, and I would like to stay it that way if possible:

[My current test MKAnnotationView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLBIH.png)

I would like to navigate to a different viewcontroller when tapped inside the image or show a TableView from the bottom of the screen. For now I really just need to see how to register tapped gesture inside so I can move forward with the functionality.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `didSelect` method.

e.g.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    // navigate to a different viewcontroller
    //   or show a TableView from the bottom of the screen
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that¨s exactly what I was looking for, is there also a way how to filter userLocation out of this? Thanks

Comment: Try ‘if view.annotation == mapView.userLocation { // this is userLocation }’

Comment: Thanks very much! Cheers

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer as a solution if my solution was helpful.